# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, arguments, positional-argument

My code is giving the error as `TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given`. tried searching for an extra argument but couldn't get one.

Tried previously answered questions but didn't get any proper solution.

My code is as follows:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class Book(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self,title,author):
        self.title=title
        self.author=author   
    @abstractmethod
    def display(): pass

#Write MyBook class
class MyBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price

    def display():
        print('Title: {}'.format(title))
        print('Author: {}'.format(author))
        print('Price: {}'.format(price))

title=input()
author=input()
price=int(input())
new_novel=MyBook(title,author,price)
new_novel.display()
```

compiler gives runtime error as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 23, in <module>
    new_novel=MyBook(title,author,price)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: To add to @gbtimmon, specifically, to explain the error message - `MyBook(title,author,price)` will pass four arguments: `(self, title, author, price)`. Meanwhile, `MyBook.__init__` is defined to expect only two: `(self, price)`. (What you wrote in `Book` is irrelevant.) Thus the error message ("__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments inside the code.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class Book(object, metaclass=ABCMeta): # 1. Why do you need meta class?
    def __init__(self, title, author):
        self.title=title
        self.author=author
    @abstractmethod
    def display(self): pass  # 2. Consider replacing with  raise NotImplementedError + missing 'self'


class MyBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, price, title, author):  # 3 You are missing two arguments in here.... (title and author)
        super(MyBook, self).__init__(title, author)  # 4 This line is missing
        self.price = price

    def display(self):
        print('Title: {}'.format(self.title))  # self missing in all three lines
        print('Author: {}'.format(self.author))
        print('Price: {}'.format(self.price))

title=input()
author=input()
price=int(input())
new_novel = MyBook(title, author, price)
new_novel.display()
```

Comment: Actually, I was solving the problem from a competitive programming site HackerRank. The `Book()` class is already defined and it is not editable. I can just write the MyBook() class for the solution. and can't even change the parameters passed

Comment: Alright, so implement the notes in the MyBook class - it should solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Python will not automatically call the init of the parent class. You need to do it explicitly.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class Book(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self,title,author):
        self.title=title
        self.author=author   
    @abstractmethod
    def display(): pass

#Write MyBook class
class MyBook(Book):
    def __init__(self, price, title, author):
        super(MyBook, self).__init__(title, author)
        self.price = price

    def display():
        print('Title: {}'.format(title))
        print('Author: {}'.format(author))
        print('Price: {}'.format(price))
```

Comment: This does not seem to be the only problem. E.g. display is not referencing to the class variables.

Comment: changing def display() to def display(self) solved the problem

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response

Comment: @Carsten it was however the problem that was generating the error OP posted. I didnt want to do *ALL* his homework for him :)